# Issue when trying to Android Archive a Maui Blazor hybrid application

Tags: android, sass, maui, maui-blazor

I'm trying to publish an apk of our Maui Blazor hybrid app from Visual Studio 2022, but when I try the Android Archive step (The first thing Publish does), I get the following error:

The Sass rule is missing the {itemtype} property

And the archive stops. I have tried both the bundle and the apk options for the output type.

If I just try and run the release version on an emulator it produces an apk, signs it, and deploys it perfectly.

Two questions: Firstly, does anybody know what that error means and how I track down what bit of SASS it doesn't like?

Secondly, What am I missing out on if I bypass the Visual Studio Publish (Builds Archive) and Deploy steps and use the apk built during the release build deploy to the emulator?

Regards
Brian

Log entry:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Publishing.ArchiveManager Error: 0 : System.InvalidOperationException: The "Sass" rule is missing the "{ItemType}" property.
   at Microsoft.Verify.Operation(Boolean condition, String unformattedMessage, Object arg1, Object arg2)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.DynamicTypeBrowseObject.<<get_ItemType>b__116_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAPropertyInfo.get_Value()
   at Clide.ItemProperties.GetValue(String name)
   at Clide.ItemProperties.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object& result)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
   at Clide.AndroidClideExtensions.<>c.<GetAndroidResources>b__1_0(IItemNode itemNode) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\ProjectSystem\Extensions.cs:line 22
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<DistinctIterator>d__64`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Publishing.AndroidArchiveToolsService.<CreateParametersAsync>d__20.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Services\Publishing\Archival\AndroidArchiveToolsService.cs:line 185
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Publishing.AndroidArchiveToolsService.<ArchiveAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Services\Publishing\Archival\AndroidArchiveToolsService.cs:line 107
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Publishing.ArchivableProjectBase.<ArchiveAsync>d__12.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Publishing\Archival\ArchivableProjectBase.cs:line 30
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Publishing.ArchiveManager.<ArchiveAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Publishing\Archival\ArchiveManager.cs:line 254: 06/06/2023 01:52:10Z
    DateTime=2023-06-06T01:52:10.0740081Z: 06/06/2023 01:52:10Z
```

Comment: Re Second Question: You’ll have to find solution eventually, to be able to upload to Google Play Console, which requires a .aab bundle.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem and more code snippets so that we can test on our side?

Comment: Sorry Jessie, Its a rather large blazor system with lots of SASS vars and definitions.  I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of the piece of SASS that is causing the issue or maybe a way of turning on logs for the Archive process.

Comment: I've found the logs.  Looks like Android Archiver is throwing an InvalidOperationException

Comment: Could you please post the full error log with details?

Comment: Hi @JessieZhang-MSFT.  I have posted feedback with logs at the following [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Maui-Xamarin-Android-Archiver-throwing/10385284?port=1026&fsid=204cba0f-d6c1-4439-be97-56b60880ecd3&ref=native&refTime=1687487370752&refUserId=e154dba8-0fd9-66ed-a1aa-25a4d96b3289)