# Error in Publisher when using sass with a Maui Blazor Hybrid project

Tags: sass, blazor, maui, hybrid-mobile-app, maui-blazor

I am getting an error when I try to Publish to Android a Maui Blazor Hybrid app using sass.  The error is:

The sass rule is missing the {item type} property.

This post is further to my june post:
[Issue when trying to Android Archive a Maui Blazor hybrid application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411283/issue-when-trying-to-android-archive-a-maui-blazor-hybrid-application)

I have now reproduced the issue in a test project.  The steps to recreate the issue are as follows:

- Create a new project using the Maui Blazor Hybrid template (Select .Net 7.0)
- Add the nuget package DartSassBuilder v1.0 to the project
- Add a sass file to the Counter.razor page (Counter.razor.scss)
- Add a class to the sass file and use it in the Counter.razor page
- Select the Release configuration
- Select an Android Emulator
- Build the project
- Select Publish from the projects context menu
- After a while the error is produced and the publish process stops

Has anybody go any ideas how I can get passed this issue?

Regards
Brian